# Template row in grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

This is possible change row template for jqGrid? For example, we have four columns and I want to get something like that:

[image]

If this is impossible can you suggest other free components for this task? It wolud be better if this component have paging, search, sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but it's very unclear what you mean. Which "template row" you mean? jqGrid use HTML `<table>` as basis for the grid and every row of data will be represented as one `<tr>` element.

So if you have some database table with 4 columns and you want to display one row from the database as two rows on HTML page you can provide the data for jqGrid in 2 columns instead of 4 columns, but with twice number of rows.

I don't understand how you want interpret sorting and search in such grid, but if you will use `datatype: "json"` or `datatype: "xml"` then your server code will be responsible for sorting and searching of data, so you can in general implement your custom behavior in the case.

Comment: :Thanks for answer. I want something like listview. And, some grids support this feature, but they not free. The Devexpress Grid for example. This is demo: http://mvc.devexpress.com/GridView/Templates

Comment: @user1260827: You are welcome! You can't use jqGrid like in the way from the demo which you referenced. To tell the trust I personally find the look of information from the demo very very gad because column headers are mixed with the values ("First Name" with "Janet") in the demo. I think that one placed pictures with girls to concentrate the user on picture and not on the information. The outer table with headers have nothing common with the inner table with the row. The column headers have no sense in my opinion. In any way jqGrid don't support such view.